# Fixed html table header row and left column using pure css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set table header and table column fixed. I have found some other code on stackoverflow itself as well, but all of them seems to be an example of single header row.

In case of mine its actually 2 header row, and want to fix 6 left column. Here is my example:

```css
#matrixTable_wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: relative;
}

#matrixTable thead th {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
#matrixTable thead th.fixed-row {
      position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
#matrixTable thead th.fixed-col,
#matrixTable tbody td.fixed-col{
   position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.14/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div id="matrixTable_wrapper" className="no-footer">
  <table id="matrixTable" class="table matrix-table fixed-header table-bordered dataTable no-footer">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row cursor-pointer">Bldg<span></span></th>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row cursor-pointer">Unit<span><i class="ml-1 fa fa-sort-asc" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></th>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row cursor-pointer">Floor<span></span></th>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row cursor-pointer">Stack<span></span></th>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row unit_type_sts cursor-pointer">UT<span></span></th>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row unit_sqft_sts cursor-pointer">SqFt<span></span></th>
         <th colspan="1" class="fixed-row">Balcony</th>
         <th colspan="5" class="fixed-row">Floor Level</th>
         <th colspan="1" class="fixed-row">Flooring</th>
         <th colspan="1" class="fixed-row">Rent</th>
         <th colspan="5" class="fixed-row">Unclear</th>
         <th colspan="4" class="fixed-row">View/Exposure</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th title="Courtyard-Unenclosed Patio" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Courtyard-Un...<span></span></th>
         <th title="Floor Level 01" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Floor Level 01<span></span></th>
         <th title="Floor Level 02" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Floor Level 02<span></span></th>
         <th title="Floor Level 03" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Floor Level 03<span></span></th>
         <th title="Floor Level 04" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Floor Level 04<span></span></th>
         <th title="Floor Level 05" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Floor Level 05<span></span></th>
         <th title="Luxury Vinyl Planking" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Luxury Vinyl...<span></span></th>
         <th title="Rent" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Rent<span></span></th>
         <th title="Scheme 1" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Scheme 1<span></span></th>
         <th title="Scheme 3" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Scheme 3<span></span></th>
         <th title="Scheme 2" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Scheme 2<span></span></th>
         <th title="Noise" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Noise<span></span></th>
         <th title="Limited Natural Light" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Limited Natu...<span></span></th>
         <th title="View - Pool" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">View - Pool<span></span></th>
         <th title="View - Obstructed" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">View - Obstr...<span></span></th>
         <th title="View - Courtyard" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">View - Court...<span></span></th>
         <th title="View - Property Perimeter" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">View - Prope...<span></span></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixColbuilding_number" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mstbuilding_number" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                  <ul id="multiSelectMatrixDropDownbuilding_number" class="scrollable-menu multiselect-container dropdown-menu pull-right" x-placement="top-start" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: top, left;">
                     <li data-value="---" class="multiselect-item multiselect-item-0"><a tabindex="0" class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox" title="---"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row-0 other-checkbox" name="col_building_number[]" data-col-name="building_number" value="---" checked="">Select All</label></a></li>
                     <li data-value="1" class="multiselect-item multiselect-item-1"><a tabindex="1" class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox" title="1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row-1 other-checkbox" name="col_building_number[]" data-col-name="building_number" value="1" checked="">1</label></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">

         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixColfloor" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mstfloor" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
           
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixColunit_type" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mstunit_type" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
           
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63982" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63982" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
           
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63984" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63984" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
               
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
          
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63987" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63987" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                  
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63974" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63974" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63973" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63973" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63978" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63978" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
          
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63983" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63983" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                  
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
          
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63979" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63979" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col">
           
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63985" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63985" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="fixed-col">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">1109</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">109</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">32115a5</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">916</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>125</td>
         <td>1817</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fixed-col">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">1110</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">110</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">32115a1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">723</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>1575</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fixed-col">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">1111</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">111</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">32115a2f</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">787</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>1615</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fixed-col">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">1112</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">112</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">32115a4</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">859</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>1709</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fixed-col">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">1113</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">113</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">32115a5</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">916</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>1817</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fixed-col">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">1115</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">115</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">32115a2e</td>
         <td class="fixed-col">773</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>1615</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>

   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

The code might seems little long, but basically it follows this basic structure:

```
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
         //with some column as rowspan=2
      </tr>
      <tr>
         //here other th listed where rowspan not equal 2
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            //here is a select checkbox field
         </th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        // here td of body
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In case if you need js fiddle you can find it here. https://jsfiddle.net/7bj6mngh/

#PS: I have removed some code from select on some col, because of character limit on SO, but full working code is in jsfiddle.

Comment: Use flexbox or grid and then you can choose the elements inside those for sticky.

Comment: could you please share it in jsfiddle

Comment: Here it is: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Should I set table or table container as flex?

Comment: You have to eliminate the usage of table tags and use <div> elements first.

Comment: @m4n0 this is obviously tabular data, using a div is not the correct approach.

Comment: So you want the 2 header rows and the 6 leftmost table columns to stay fixed when you scroll? That doesn't seem like a great UX, do you have a mockup of how you expect this to look?

Comment: @AayushDahal Try reading some articles on the web like this: https://adamlynch.com/flexible-data-tables-with-css-grid/ CSS grid is even better than flexbox because you can working on two dimensional layouts.

Comment: You can use `position: sticky;` for this, as described here — https://css-tricks.com/a-table-with-both-a-sticky-header-and-a-sticky-first-column/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just got to specify a left value for columns that needs to be fixed horizontally that you can get by checking their `offsetLeft` value as you can see I have created `col` class which specifies left value as per their position  and for vertical fixed header just specify `top:0` and `position:sticky`

Also use `border-collapse:separate` not `collapse` because in collapse the border top and bottom of `th` or `td` also gets attached to surrounding elements so they won't stick.

#### This will work

```css
#matrixTable_wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: relative;
}

#matrixTable thead th {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
#matrixTable thead th.fixed-row {
     
}
#matrixTable thead th.fixed-col,
#matrixTable tbody td.fixed-col{
  
}

.sticky_header
{
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 10000;
    background: white;
}


.sticky_left
{
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: white;
}
.col_1
{
left: 0px;
}
.col_2
{
left: 265px;
}
.col_3
{
    left: 326px;
}
.col_4
{
left: 591px;
}
.col_5
{
    left: 656px;
}
.col_6
{
left: 921px;
}

#matrixTable
{
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.14/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="matrixTable_wrapper" className="no-footer">
  <table id="matrixTable" class="table matrix-table fixed-header table-bordered dataTable no-footer">
   <thead class="sticky_header">
      <tr>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row cursor-pointer sticky_left col_1">Bldg<span></span></th>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row cursor-pointer sticky_left col_2">Unit<span><i class="ml-1 fa fa-sort-asc" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></th>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row cursor-pointer sticky_left col_3">Floor<span></span></th>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row cursor-pointer sticky_left col_4">Stack<span></span></th>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row unit_type_sts cursor-pointer sticky_left col_5">UT<span></span></th>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row unit_sqft_sts cursor-pointer sticky_left col_6">SqFt<span></span></th>
         <th colspan="1" class="fixed-row">Balcony</th>
         <th colspan="5" class="fixed-row">Floor Level</th>
         <th colspan="1" class="fixed-row">Flooring</th>
         <th colspan="1" class="fixed-row">Rent</th>
         <th colspan="5" class="fixed-row">Unclear</th>
         <th colspan="4" class="fixed-row">View/Exposure</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th title="Courtyard-Unenclosed Patio" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Courtyard-Un...<span></span></th>
         <th title="Floor Level 01" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Floor Level 01<span></span></th>
         <th title="Floor Level 02" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Floor Level 02<span></span></th>
         <th title="Floor Level 03" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Floor Level 03<span></span></th>
         <th title="Floor Level 04" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Floor Level 04<span></span></th>
         <th title="Floor Level 05" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Floor Level 05<span></span></th>
         <th title="Luxury Vinyl Planking" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Luxury Vinyl...<span></span></th>
         <th title="Rent" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Rent<span></span></th>
         <th title="Scheme 1" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Scheme 1<span></span></th>
         <th title="Scheme 3" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Scheme 3<span></span></th>
         <th title="Scheme 2" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Scheme 2<span></span></th>
         <th title="Noise" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Noise<span></span></th>
         <th title="Limited Natural Light" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Limited Natu...<span></span></th>
         <th title="View - Pool" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">View - Pool<span></span></th>
         <th title="View - Obstructed" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">View - Obstr...<span></span></th>
         <th title="View - Courtyard" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">View - Court...<span></span></th>
         <th title="View - Property Perimeter" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">View - Prope...<span></span></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col sticky_left col_1">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixColbuilding_number" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mstbuilding_number" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                  <ul id="multiSelectMatrixDropDownbuilding_number" class="scrollable-menu multiselect-container dropdown-menu pull-right" x-placement="top-start" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: top, left;">
                     <li data-value="---" class="multiselect-item multiselect-item-0"><a tabindex="0" class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox" title="---"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row-0 other-checkbox" name="col_building_number[]" data-col-name="building_number" value="---" checked="">Select All</label></a></li>
                     <li data-value="1" class="multiselect-item multiselect-item-1"><a tabindex="1" class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox" title="1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row-1 other-checkbox" name="col_building_number[]" data-col-name="building_number" value="1" checked="">1</label></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col sticky_left col_2">

         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col sticky_left col_3">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixColfloor" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mstfloor" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col sticky_left col_4">
           
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col sticky_left col_5">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixColunit_type" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mstunit_type" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col sticky_left col_6">
           
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63982" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63982" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
           
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63984" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63984" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
               
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
          
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63987" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63987" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                  
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63974" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63974" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63973" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63973" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63978" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63978" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
          
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63983" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63983" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                  
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
          
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63979" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63979" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col">
           
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63985" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63985" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_1">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_2">1109</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_3">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_4">109</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_5">32115a5</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_6">916</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>125</td>
         <td>1817</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_1">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_2">1110</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_3">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_4">110</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_5">32115a1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_6">723</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>1575</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      
       <tr>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_1">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_2">1110</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_3">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_4">110</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_5">32115a1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_6">723</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>1575</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>

 <tr>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_1">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_2">1110</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_3">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_4">110</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_5">32115a1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_6">723</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>1575</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>

      
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer seems pretty close, but could you please confirm why border is missing on those fixed header and row on scroll

Comment: @AayushDahal use border-collapse: separate not collapse i have also explained the reason for the same

Answer (score 0):

```css
#matrixTable_wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: relative;
}

#matrixTable thead th {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
#matrixTable thead {
      position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
#matrixTable thead th.fixed-col,
#matrixTable tbody td.fixed-col{
   position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="matrixTable_wrapper" className="no-footer">
  <table id="matrixTable" class="table matrix-table fixed-header table-bordered dataTable no-footer">
   <thead class="sticky_header">
      <tr>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row cursor-pointer sticky_left col_1">Bldg<span></span></th>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row cursor-pointer sticky_left col_2">Unit<span><i class="ml-1 fa fa-sort-asc" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></th>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row cursor-pointer sticky_left col_3">Floor<span></span></th>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row cursor-pointer sticky_left col_4">Stack<span></span></th>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row unit_type_sts cursor-pointer sticky_left col_5">UT<span></span></th>
         <th rowspan="2" class="fixed-col fixed-row unit_sqft_sts cursor-pointer sticky_left col_6">SqFt<span></span></th>
         <th colspan="1" class="fixed-row">Balcony</th>
         <th colspan="5" class="fixed-row">Floor Level</th>
         <th colspan="1" class="fixed-row">Flooring</th>
         <th colspan="1" class="fixed-row">Rent</th>
         <th colspan="5" class="fixed-row">Unclear</th>
         <th colspan="4" class="fixed-row">View/Exposure</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th title="Courtyard-Unenclosed Patio" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Courtyard-Un...<span></span></th>
         <th title="Floor Level 01" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Floor Level 01<span></span></th>
         <th title="Floor Level 02" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Floor Level 02<span></span></th>
         <th title="Floor Level 03" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Floor Level 03<span></span></th>
         <th title="Floor Level 04" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Floor Level 04<span></span></th>
         <th title="Floor Level 05" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Floor Level 05<span></span></th>
         <th title="Luxury Vinyl Planking" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Luxury Vinyl...<span></span></th>
         <th title="Rent" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Rent<span></span></th>
         <th title="Scheme 1" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Scheme 1<span></span></th>
         <th title="Scheme 3" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Scheme 3<span></span></th>
         <th title="Scheme 2" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Scheme 2<span></span></th>
         <th title="Noise" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Noise<span></span></th>
         <th title="Limited Natural Light" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">Limited Natu...<span></span></th>
         <th title="View - Pool" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">View - Pool<span></span></th>
         <th title="View - Obstructed" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">View - Obstr...<span></span></th>
         <th title="View - Courtyard" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">View - Court...<span></span></th>
         <th title="View - Property Perimeter" class="text-nowrap fixed-row cursor-pointer">View - Prope...<span></span></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col sticky_left col_1">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixColbuilding_number" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mstbuilding_number" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                  <ul id="multiSelectMatrixDropDownbuilding_number" class="scrollable-menu multiselect-container dropdown-menu pull-right" x-placement="top-start" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: top, left;">
                     <li data-value="---" class="multiselect-item multiselect-item-0"><a tabindex="0" class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox" title="---"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row-0 other-checkbox" name="col_building_number[]" data-col-name="building_number" value="---" checked="">Select All</label></a></li>
                     <li data-value="1" class="multiselect-item multiselect-item-1"><a tabindex="1" class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox" title="1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row-1 other-checkbox" name="col_building_number[]" data-col-name="building_number" value="1" checked="">1</label></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col sticky_left col_2">

         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col sticky_left col_3">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixColfloor" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mstfloor" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col sticky_left col_4">
           
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col sticky_left col_5">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixColunit_type" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mstunit_type" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col sticky_left col_6">
           
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63982" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63982" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
           
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63984" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63984" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
               
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
          
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63987" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63987" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                  
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63974" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63974" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63973" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63973" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63978" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63978" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                 
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
          
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63983" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63983" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                  
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
          
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col ">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63979" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63979" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col">
           
         </th>
         <th class="fixed-row fixed-col">
            <span class="multiselect-native-select">
               <select multiple="" id="multiSelectMatrixCol63985" class="form-control multiSelect"></select>
               <div class="btn-group" style="width: 240px;">
                  <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-html="true" title="All" aria-expanded="false" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span id="mst63985" class="multiselect-selected-text">All</span> <b class="caret"></b></button> 
                
               </div>
            </span>
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_1">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_2">1109</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_3">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_4">109</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_5">32115a5</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_6">916</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>125</td>
         <td>1817</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_1">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_2">1110</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_3">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_4">110</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_5">32115a1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_6">723</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>1575</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      
       <tr>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_1">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_2">1110</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_3">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_4">110</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_5">32115a1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_6">723</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>1575</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>

 <tr>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_1">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_2">1110</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_3">1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_4">110</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_5">32115a1</td>
         <td class="fixed-col sticky_left col_6">723</td>
         <td></td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4vchqb1p/

I have made complete head sticky, that's possible method using only CSS.

Comment: Does not seems to be working, please check if you have used correct js fiddle link

Comment: I have regenrated the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/hq4eftyr/

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks like it's working fine, (from your code snippet), I believe the thing that you missed was adding a `background-color` to the specific field that you want to get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`position: sticky;` is the way to go. In this example I have fixed two rows and two columns.

```css
table {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
th, td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: white;
}
thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}
thead th {
  background-color: #f0f0ff;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
}
thead td {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
td:first-child, th:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
}
td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(2) {
  position: sticky;
  left: 100px;
}
tbody td:first-child {
  z-index: 8;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <th>Header 5</th>
      <th>Header 6</th>
      <th>Header 7</th>
      <th>Header 8</th>
      <th>Header 9</th>
      <th>Header 10</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fixed 1</td>
      <td>Fixed 2</td>
      <td>Fixed 3</td>
      <td>Fixed 4</td>
      <td>Fixed 5</td>
      <td>Fixed 6</td>
      <td>Fixed 7</td>
      <td>Fixed 8</td>
      <td>Fixed 9</td>
      <td>Fixed 10</td>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Australia</td>
      <td>Aardvark</td>
      <td>A4</td>
      <td>A5</td>
      <td>A6</td>
      <td>A7</td>
      <td>A8</td>
      <td>A9</td>
      <td>A10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>Botswana</td>
      <td>Bison</td>
      <td>B4</td>
      <td>B5</td>
      <td>B6</td>
      <td>B7</td>
      <td>B8</td>
      <td>B9</td>
      <td>B10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cherry</td>
      <td>Cameroon</td>
      <td>Cheetah</td>
      <td>C4</td>
      <td>C5</td>
      <td>C6</td>
      <td>C7</td>
      <td>C8</td>
      <td>C9</td>
      <td>C10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Durian</td>
      <td>Denmark</td>
      <td>Duck</td>
      <td>D4</td>
      <td>D5</td>
      <td>D6</td>
      <td>D7</td>
      <td>D8</td>
      <td>D9</td>
      <td>D10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Elderberry</td>
      <td>Eritrea</td>
      <td>Elephant</td>
      <td>E4</td>
      <td>E5</td>
      <td>E6</td>
      <td>E7</td>
      <td>E8</td>
      <td>E9</td>
      <td>E10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fig</td>
      <td>Finland</td>
      <td>Flamingo</td>
      <td>F4</td>
      <td>F5</td>
      <td>F6</td>
      <td>F7</td>
      <td>F8</td>
      <td>F9</td>
      <td>F10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Grape</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
      <td>Gorilla</td>
      <td>G4</td>
      <td>G5</td>
      <td>G6</td>
      <td>G7</td>
      <td>G8</td>
      <td>G9</td>
      <td>G10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Honeydew</td>
      <td>Honduras</td>
      <td>Hummingbird</td>
      <td>H4</td>
      <td>H5</td>
      <td>H6</td>
      <td>H7</td>
      <td>H8</td>
      <td>H9</td>
      <td>H10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Icaco</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
      <td>Ibis</td>
      <td>I4</td>
      <td>I5</td>
      <td>I6</td>
      <td>I7</td>
      <td>I8</td>
      <td>I9</td>
      <td>I10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jackfruit</td>
      <td>Japan</td>
      <td>Jacana</td>
      <td>J4</td>
      <td>J5</td>
      <td>J6</td>
      <td>J7</td>
      <td>J8</td>
      <td>J9</td>
      <td>J10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kiwifruit</td>
      <td>Kenya</td>
      <td>Kangaroo</td>
      <td>I4</td>
      <td>I5</td>
      <td>I6</td>
      <td>I7</td>
      <td>I8</td>
      <td>I9</td>
      <td>I10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lemon</td>
      <td>Libya</td>
      <td>Leopard</td>
      <td>L4</td>
      <td>L5</td>
      <td>L6</td>
      <td>L7</td>
      <td>L8</td>
      <td>L9</td>
      <td>L10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mango</td>
      <td>Morocco</td>
      <td>Monkey</td>
      <td>M4</td>
      <td>M5</td>
      <td>M6</td>
      <td>M7</td>
      <td>M8</td>
      <td>M9</td>
      <td>M10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nashi</td>
      <td>Nigeria</td>
      <td>Nightingale</td>
      <td>N4</td>
      <td>N5</td>
      <td>N6</td>
      <td>N7</td>
      <td>N8</td>
      <td>N9</td>
      <td>N10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Oman</td>
      <td>Octopus</td>
      <td>O4</td>
      <td>O5</td>
      <td>O6</td>
      <td>O7</td>
      <td>O8</td>
      <td>O9</td>
      <td>O10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pear</td>
      <td>Peru</td>
      <td>Pelican</td>
      <td>P4</td>
      <td>P5</td>
      <td>P6</td>
      <td>P7</td>
      <td>P8</td>
      <td>P9</td>
      <td>P10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quince</td>
      <td>Qatar</td>
      <td>Quail</td>
      <td>Q4</td>
      <td>Q5</td>
      <td>Q6</td>
      <td>Q7</td>
      <td>Q8</td>
      <td>Q9</td>
      <td>Q10</td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```